# Can I change the screen resolution?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, display, resolution

I got a laptop with 17 inche screen. However, it is not that comfort as the text appears small. The recommended resolution is 1600x900 but I want to change it to something smaller. My question is: if I change it to something else will that hurt my eyes? as I tried to change it and when I did it seems that the screen is not that clear as it was with 1600x900 although the difference is small.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With LCD monitors, it's not advisable to use a resolution different from the screen's native one; this creates a lot of problems with scaling, often leading to distorted and/or blurry images, and also doesn't allow the use of sub-pixel rendering for fonts (ClearType).

A really better solution would be increasing the default text size. This setting can be easily reached from the same place where you configure the screen resolution, by selecting the option "Make text and other items larger or smaller".

Comment: Good. But first time I notice that 15 Inche screens are better, do you agree with me? :)

Comment: No :-) You can use larger fonts on a high-resolution screen, but you can't use smaller fonts on a low-resolution one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change the resolution to something lower like 1366x768. It'll be slightly blurry, but I doubt it'll hurt your eyes or anything.

You could also try increasing the DPI, which makes on-screen text and other UI elements larger without affecting resolution, but this doesn't work 100% reliably with all programs. Still, might be worth a try. Just type "DPI" into the Start menu search and click on the first result (which should be "Make text or other items larger or smaller").

Answer (score 0):

keep the recommended resolution but what you can do is from your resolution screen go click on display then you will have a window with 3 size options small, medium, large choose the option that will work for you so that anything that you open will be larger or medium size but still with a good resolution